# Can I mount a Wubi .disk image in a new Wubi installation?

Tags: wubi

I've bricked my Ubuntu Wubi installation and as a result I can't get to the log-in screen. The computer sits at a blank, off-black (that kinda deep red/brown) screen after I've selected which Kernel to boot.

Is there any way I can install a fresh copy of Ubuntu via Wubi and then mount the old image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you'd use a live CD - since you might be able to repair the current Wubi install. If you need data off it you could also try [ext2read](http://ext2read.blogspot.com/), which gives read-only access to the root.disk from Windows.

If you decide to access via a new Wubi install, it's critical to copy the `*.disk` files *outside* the `\ubuntu` directory before installing, since the first step of the Wubi install is to remove any existing install - and that deletes everything. Normally (on NTFS) there is only the `root.disk` that you care about, but if you install on a `FAT32` partition or created a separate virtual disk for `/home` you can have others.

Let's say you moved (quicker than copy) the `root.disk` to `\ubuntubackup\root.disk`. Then when you install a fresh Wubi on the same 'drive', you can mount the old one as follows:

```
sudo mount -o loop /host/ubuntubackup/root.disk /mnt
```

Then you can use `nautilus` (or some other file browser) to view the files e.g. from a command prompt you could enter: `nautilus /mnt/home`

**Attempting repairs**

Wubi problems are often caused by hard reboots, perhaps after an apparent freeze. Forced shutdowns can damage any filesystem, but Wubi is more sensitive since it's whole partition is virtual, the `root.disk`. The steps to fix are:

- Run `chkdsk /f` (or /r) from Windows. The corruption can be on `NTFS` and/or on the `ext3/4` filesystem within the `root.disk`. In your case, you get past the grub menu, so it's probably only the `ext3/4` filesystem, but I might run `chkdsk` anyway.
- After `chkdsk` check that the `root.disk` is still there. This may sound strange, but Windows will sometimes move files it repairs to a hidden `\found.000` directory. It may rename the `root.disk` to `chk0000.chk` so look for it by size (5-30GB). See [this](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2011/08/missing-rootdisk.html) for more info.
- Now run `fsck` on the root.disk. You'll need to boot an Ubuntu CD or USB for this. Then mount the host `NTFS` partition. E.g. if your `root.disk` is on `/dev/sda3`:

  `sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt`

  sudo fsck /mnt/ubuntu/disks/root.disk

**Other possibilities**

- You could try booting an older kernel.
- Boot in recovery mode.
- Check there's enough free space to boot (by mounting the root.disk from the live CD and then freeing up space if required, or [resizing on the fly](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10590851&postcount=2)).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As an aside, do you have any links to diagnosing why it won't boot?

Comment: That depends on how it broke in the first place, but I'll add some general steps to my post above.

Comment: I've recently seen a post on problems booting after updating Oneiric kernels. So make sure you check the older kernels. If you don't see the grub menu at boot time, hold down the SHIFT key immediately after selecting Ubuntu from the Windows Boot Manager. Then you can look under Previous Linux Versions for older kernels.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use wubi. Boot into the fresh Ubuntu and click 'Try Ubuntu' then you might be able to mount the old Ubuntu. I'm not sure you could boot into the old image though. but if you mount the old system you could possibly backup some files if you wanted.